# Shebang to embed <*your language*> in Windows BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, shebang

How do you embed scripting language inside BAT file in Windows?

Effectively I am after **Unix shebang** for Windows: put JS/C#/Python/Java text into a BAT file, have a small header on top then have it compiled/run by just running the container BAT file.

---

Some scripting engines are guaranteed to exist: **VBScript**, **JS**, **MSHTA/HTML** — are there good shebangs for those?

Others are technically optional, but may be expected: **C#**, **VB.NET**, **PowerShell**, **node.js**, **Python** — any clues as to how to wrap those with a shebang?

Finally, there might be a way to smuggle a **compiled binary** within a BAT file, and shake/goad OS into running it. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You should reword the question to not ask for examples, but instead ask "How do I...". It's great to ask and answer your own question, but the question should still stand on its own like any question, and asking for examples is kinda not recommended.

Comment: Thanks @hyde I've reworded and expanded. I've had some of those proto-shebangs in use for years, and hope people add/expand/criticise for the better, and also it's great to have it documented somewhere on internet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two useful Javascript shebangs I've come across. Those are crafted for CSCRIPT, MS JScript guaranteed to be bundled with Windows. Can be trivially retargeted for node.js too -- if you're certain node.js would be on the path at runtime.

DARTH shebang, called after the `/*-*\` smiley:

```
title /*-*\&@cscript/nologo /E:jscript %~f0 %*&@goto:EOF&:*/=0

WScript.Echo('OK');
```

Stealth clubman shebang, called after the scary man with a club emoticon:

```
0</* :
@cscript/nologo /E:jscript %~f0 %*&@goto:EOF&:*/0

WScript.Echo('OK');
```

The tradeoff between those two is whether we make it apparent the script is shebanged at runtime or have a more conspicuous header. DARTH would print one line to console, and set the console title. Stealth clubman would take two lines at the JS header.